Cipher not initialized during storing Secret key in keystore
 fun wrapKey(wrappingKey: SecretKey, secretKey: String): Pair<ByteArray, ByteArray> {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, wrappingKey)
        } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
            Log.e("KeyError", "Invalid Key: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("CipherError", "Unexpected Error: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


        val iv = cipher.iv // Initialization vector
        val wrappedKey = cipher.doFinal(secretKey.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

        return Pair(iv, wrappedKey)
    }

I am using KeyStore system to secur my key for encryption and descryption. when i am wrapping my key in keystore getting issue during encode my secret key
